# SignalR stream works only after Forced Refresh in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

I have an MVC 5 Web Application that implements SignalR for Web Socket functionality.

In Production, Mounted on Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.5 it generates an error where connected clients only receive the stream after doing a forced refresh on the browser.

This replicates even on machines and browsers where it has never been opened, which makes me think is not a Browser Cache Issue.

This does not replicate on development.

There is also a domain difference on the environments:

On development I use localhost:61350

On production I use mydomain.com/MyWebApp

So files are not served from the root domain on production, they are served using the Virtual Path.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Edit 1:

The issue is confirmed to be replicated on:

Google Chrome
Firefox
Opera
Edge
Safari IOS

These are just the browsers I have access to and made the test on.

Comment: Can you check the javascript console in the browsers to know which is exactly the error?

Comment: There is no error thrown, when the Issue Happens, when it works fine, it logs every update as expected but only when I force a refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by moving the SignalR start() call out of $(document).ready(). I have no idea why that would cause a problem, but in my case it did. I am using .NET 4.7 (but have tried 4.5 & 4.6) and jQuery 3.2.1.

**Only works on refresh:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Works all the time:**

```
<script>
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        ...
    });
</script>
```